# rails - why polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

An example from this [blog](http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/activerecord_polymorphic.html)

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :taggable_id, :taggable_type
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
end


class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :tags, :as => :taggable  
end

class Bike < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :tags, :as => :taggable
end
```

It looks to me we could do thing like this without polymorphic associations

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, 
  belongs_to :cars,
  belongs_to :bikes,
end


class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :tags
end

class Bike < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :tags
end
```

What is the difference of with polymorphic associations and without?

THanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your last example, Car has many tags, so conventionally the "tags" table will have a field `car_id`. Now Bike has many tags, so one more field `bike_id`.

Without Polymorphic, how many fields are you going to create for the tags table? :)

Even you guarantee that there will only be two models have tag ultimately, there will also lots of null data in the table, say a bike doesn't have car_id, and that is not nice.

Polymorphism solved this problem by defining a common interface so that Car and Bike can share same operations with different sub type. http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming.html

Answer (score 2):

A polymorphic association allows you to create a table with relationships between multiple models.

Consider your example.  Both `Car` and `Bike` can have many `tags`, so instead of creating two different tables, say `car_tags` and `bike_tags`, you can use a single ***polymorphic*** table named `Tag` which not only stores the foreign key (in a column named `resource_id`), but also the *type* of resource it's associated with (in a column named `resource_type`), which, in this case would be `Car` or `Bike`.

In summary, polymorphic relationships are between *many different* models whereas normal relationships are, generally speaking, only between two.

You can find more information in the RoR Guides; http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Hope that helps clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphic associations allow for a single model to belong to multiple models on a single association[1]. Taking your example above, simply adding `has_many :tags` to the `Car` and `Bike` models and `belongs_to :car` and `belongs_to :bike` to the `Tag` model has two major shortcomings:

1. It introduces a glut of foreign keys of which a large quantity will have no value
2. It still doesn't allow for a tag to belong to more than one model

Some great resources for learning more about polymorphic associations are listed below.

1. [RailsGuides on Polymorphic
   Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)
2. [RailsCasts #154 Polymorphic Associations
   (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised)
3. [What's the Deal with Rails' Polymorphic
   Associations?](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/whats-the-deal-with-rails-polymorphic-associations)